# Attempt to apply to the table in <tr> in the ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the HTML organized as follows.

```
   <tr ng-style="{height : hideTagContainer? '38px': '140px'}">
                    <td><img src="../assets/images/icon_condition_coment.png"></td>
                    <td>2014.01.06 16:05</td>
                    <td>Subject</td>
                    <td>Message
                   <div class=“comment-container" ng-show="hideButton">
                    <div class=“coment-list" ng-show="modal">
                    <span class="list-image"><img src="../assets/images/icon_condition_coment.png" style="top:7px;"></span>
                    <span class="list-name”>comment-name</span>
                    <span class="list-time">2014.01.05 13:00</span>
                    <span class="list-message”>reply-messsage</span>
                    </div>
                    <textarea class=“reply-comment" ng-show="clicked[$index]”>OK, I got it</textarea><br/>
                    <span class=“reply-submit" ng-show="clicked[$index]" ng-click="itemIsClicked($index)"></span>
                   </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="head-logo" ng-click="hideTagContainer(0)" ng-class="{'head-logo': hideButton ,'head-logo folded': !hideButton}"></span>
                      <input type="button" class="comment" value=“OK" ng-click="popupDelete()"></td>
     </tr>
<tr ng-style="{height : hideTagContainer? '38px': '140px'}">
                    <td><img src="../assets/images/icon_condition_coment.png"></td>
                    <td>2014.01.06 17:05</td>
                    <td>Subject2</td>
                    <td>Message2
                   <div class=“comment-container" ng-show="hideButton">
                    <div class=“coment-list" ng-show="modal">
                    <span class="list-image"><img src="../assets/images/icon_condition_coment.png" style="top:7px;"></span>
                    <span class="list-name”>comment-name2</span>
                    <span class="list-time">2014.01.05 14:00</span>
                    <span class="list-message”>reply-messsage2</span>
                    </div>
                    <textarea class=“reply-comment" ng-show="clicked[$index]”>OK, I got it</textarea><br/>
                    <span class=“reply-submit" ng-show="clicked[$index]" ng-click="itemIsClicked($index)"></span>
                   </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="head-logo" ng-click="hideTagContainer(1)" ng-class="{'head-logo': hideButton ,'head-logo folded': !hideButton}"></span>
                      <input type="button" class="comment" value=“OK" ng-click="popupDelete()"></td>
     </tr>
```

I'm trying to change the style of each of tr through hideTagContainer (index).

HideTagcontainer of JS is coded as follows:

```
scope.hideButton = false;               

scope.hideTagContainer = function (index) {
    scope.hideButton = !scope.hideButton;
};
```

How Will To run the hidetagcontainer in each ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store all the "hide" variable in an array:

```
$scope.hideRows = [];
for(var i = 0; i < rowNumber; i ++) $scope.hideRows[i] = false; 
//rowNumber is the number of <tr> row

$scope.hideTagContainer = function (index) {
     $scope.hideRows[index] = !$scope.hideRows[index];
};
```

The html for each  should be:

```
<tr ng-style="{height : hideRows[1]? '38px': '140px'}">  
  <!-- Other HTML -->
  <span class="head-logo" ng-click="hideTagContainer(1)" ng-class="{'head-logo': hideRows[1],'head-logo folded': !hideRows[1]}"></span>
</tr>
```

Comment: hmm.....How Can ng-class too, to take effect? 
If you now run the hideTagContainer, ng-class is <tr> Is there a way to solve the two are equally applicable?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please say it more clearly.

Comment: <tr ng-style = "{height: hideRows [1] '38px':? '140px'}">
 
The part that causes this part as follows:

<span class = "head-logo" ng-click = "hideTagContainer (1)" ng-class = "{'head-logo': hideButton, 'head-logo folded':! hideButton}"> </ span>

To change the image to match the ng-class when you click on

<tr> are changed as the two makes him ng-class, I want to fix this.